# error TS2300: Duplicate indentifier after moving my code to Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli-v6, type-definition

I am currently in the process of moving our code to Angular CLI. It is a hybrid app so the idea is to move the Angular part to CLI where as AngularJS part continues to be built by custom Webpack. Note that the application both (Angular and AngularJS part) can be built successfully using custom webpack without any errors.

Now that I am moving to Angular CLI, I am getting

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'xxxxx'

from one of our type definition files (.d.ts). This type definition file is generated from another app and fetched via npm from our internal npm servers. It does have same identifiers declared multiple times and we also reference types from (.d.ts) using import statement like :-

```
import {IABC, IEFG} from 'type-definition-file';
```

Because of this I guess, even whey I specify 'node_modules' in exclude for tsconfig, the .d.ts file is transpiled.

Considering I cannot change the .d.ts file is there any other way to get rid of this error? Why was it not a problem with custom webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In tsconfig set **skipLibCheck: true**.